# Can't present data in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am trying to retrive each row from database and keep  value in dictionary. After that I have created a array of dictionary. But when i am trying to show each value of dictionary in table cell, i can't . Here is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
   var borrowerInformation:NSMutableDictionary? = NSMutableDictionary();
   var borrowerName:String = ""
   var givenDate:String = ""
   var borrower:NSMutableArray = []

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      dataQuery()
   }
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return self.borrower.count

  }
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BorrowerLanderTableViewCell

      cell.borrowerName.text = self.borrower[indexPath.row]  as? String

     return cell
  }

  func dataQuery(){
    let queryBorrower = PFQuery(className:"BorrowerLander")
    queryBorrower.whereKey("borrowerLander", equalTo: 0)
    queryBorrower.whereKey("userId", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)
    queryBorrower.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        self.borrower = NSMutableArray()
        if error == nil {
            if let borrowerData = objects {
                for object in borrowerData {
                    self.borrowerName = object["name"] as! String
                    self.givenDate = object["givenDate"] as! String
                    self.borrowerInformation = [ "borrowerName": self.borrowerName,"givenDate":"self.givenDate"]
                    self.borrower.addObject(self.borrowerInformation!)
                }
            }


        } 
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
 }
}
```

Here, i have just added main part of the code. Please tell me how can i show  value of array of the dictionary in table view cell?

Comment: are you getting value properly in array , if yes then after dataquery method execution put breakpoint on numberofrow of tableview method to check , how many rows it returning , if no row then no value will be shown .

Comment: return 3 rows. But can't show.

Comment: if let mBorrowValue = self.borrower[indexPath.row]  as? String { cell.borrowerName.text = mBorrowValue  } else { cell.borrowerName.text = "no data"} this way try once

Comment: What is the error you run into? nothing is displayed in the tableView? the wrong info is displayed tableView? The code crashes?

Comment: nothing is displayed in the tableView @Moriya

Comment: Try the last row of my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you did the setup but an issue could be that you have not set your tableviews delegate and datasource to the controller you are working with.

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

I'm also wondering if you did implement the numberOfRows and numberOfSections delegate methods.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return borrower.count
}
```

and

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Also when setting the text you need to actually use the name string you added to the dictionary

```
let borrower = self.borrower[indexPath.row]
if let name = borrower["borrowerName"] as? String{
    cell.borrowerName.text = name
} esle {
    cell.borrowerName.text = "error" 
}
```

Also declare your data array as

```
var borrower:[[String: AnyObject]] = []
```

Extra edit:

I do want to say that I really think you should use a custom object here instead of an dictionary

```
class Borrower {
    var name: String
    var givenDate: String
//etc.
    init(name: String, givenDate: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.givenDate = givenDate
    }
}
```

enabling the following

```
var borrower:[Borrower] = []
```

and in the query:

```
for object in borrowerData {
    if let name = object["name"] as? String, givenDate = object["givenDate"] as? String {
        self.borrower.append(Borrower(name: name, givenDate: giverDate))
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath, do you ever break there?

Comment: I think, you realise my problem. I have use your code. But showing this error `Ambiguous use of subscript`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Look `func loadSampleMeals()` and `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html . I am trying to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, if you read that article you see they are using a class called Meal. You should do that to instead of creating dictionaries to represent your objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110931/discussion-between-moriya-and-alamin).

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you've set the `dataSource` and `delegate` for your table view to your view controller. Then, the function `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will never get called unless you implement `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`. The default implementation of that function returns 0. Try implementing this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return borrower.count
}
```

Also, if the code inside of `queryBorrower.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {` is actually in the background, you need to dispatch your table view reload to the main thread. Like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [weak self] () -> Void in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: My code is work when i retrieve value  of single column and store that value in `borrower ` array. But  not working when i am trying to retrieve value of a row and store that row in a dictionary and after that create `borrower` array of that  dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `numberOf...` dataSource delegate first:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int 

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```